# Import methods without using relative path syntax

Tags: reactjs, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I want to know more about `monorepo` projects. I have a repository named `dnd` which is using [Yarn](https://lerna.js.org/) workspaces with [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/). The repository contains two main directories.

```
packages/core
packages/app
```

The `core` directory contains utility methods and the `app` directory is using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) boilerplate. Now here is the thing I want to use my utility methods in the main `app` components something like this.

```
import { concat } from '@dnd/core';
```

Currently, I am importing something like this

```
import { concat } from '../../../core/lib/utils';
```

I have to traverse the relative path with this ugly syntax. Now the path is correct but `create-react-app` throwing an error.

```
Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../core/lib/utils which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

**Is there a way we can simply import our `core` directory methods inside our `app` components with something like this.**

```
import { concat } from '@dnd/core';
```

Repositry: [Link](https://github.com/Ah-debug/dnd)

**dnd/package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "bootstrap": "lerna bootstrap --use-workspaces"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^3.21.0"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ]
}
```

**dnd/lerna.json**:

```
{
  "useWorkspaces": true,
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

**dnd/packages/core/package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "@dnd/core",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "> TODO: description",
  "homepage": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "lib/core.js",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib",
    "test": "__tests__"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: run tests from root\" && exit 1"
  }
}
```

**dnd/packages/core/lib/utils.js**:

```
export const concat = (...args) => {
    return ''.concat(...args);
};
```

**dnd/packages/app/package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "@dnd/rain",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**dnd/packages/app/src/components/App.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { concat } from '../../../core/lib/utils';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      { concat('Hello', 'World', 'Culture') }
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Disclaimer: I am typing this on the fly (without testing) based on my limited experience on my own monorepo project.

It should give you a great starting point nontheless.

### Idea

1. You would need to compile `packages/core` using microbundle or rollup into a bundle.
2. Then you want to include that bundled `packages/core` as a dependency in `packages/app`

### Setup

**`packages/core/package.json`**

- `microbundle` is a devDependency as we only require it during development.

```json
{
  "name": "@dnd/core",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "microbundle watch lib/*.js --target node"
  },
  "source": "lib/index.js", // entry point into @dnd/core
  "main": "dist/index.js",  // the compiled file/bundle that @dnd/app will reference 
  "devDependencies": [
   "microbundle": "^0.13.0"
  ]
}
```

**`packages/app/package.json`**

We add our compiled `core` package into `package/app`

```json
{
  "name": "@dnd/app"
  "dependencies": [
    "@dnd/core": 0.0.0
  ]
```

**`packages/core/lib/index.js`**

- Create an `index.js` file that will be an export of all your lib functions
- This will be your entry point for `@dnd/core`

```js
export * from './utils.js'
export * from './other-utils.js'
```

### Before Development

Before we start development, we will need to "install" the new depedencies.

```sh
lerna bootstrap
```

Then run the `npm dev` script

```sh
# this will run the npm dev script only for packages/core
cd packages/core
npm run dev
```

or

```sh
# from the root of your project (inside /dnd folder)
# this will do a `npm run dev` equivalent inside all your packages
lerna run dev
```

This will tell `microbundle` to watch for changes inside `packages/core/lib/index.js`

Whenever you change code inside `packages/core/lib/utils.js`, it will recompile the code into `packages/core/dist/index.js`

### Usages of `@dnd/core` inside `@dnd/app`

Now we can import our functions from `core` in our `app` source code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { concat } from '@dnd/core';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      { concat('Hello', 'World', 'Culture') }
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```